# Element 'th' cannot be nested in element 'table'

Tags: html, html-table, w3c-validation

Given the following HTML, why do you get the error:

> Validation (HTML5): Element 'th' cannot be nested in element 'table'

```
<table>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>text header</th>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `<th>` header cells must be defined within a table row (`<tr>`) just like `<td>`s.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You cannot have the `<th>` element outside of a `<tr>`, the following snippet is valid

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>text header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

**<th> Usage context** https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th

> Permitted parent elements
>
> A `<tr>` element.

Comment: Should have been obvious really, given the structure of HTML tables and that everything has to be in a row

Comment: I ran into this, and because the message didn't really say what it should have had in the parent elements (at least in the tool I was using), it wasn't immediately obvious. It should have been obvious sure, but everyone has their days.

Answer (score 0):

With `thead` I was getting the similar warning. This is a razor page in Visual Studio.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var customer in Model.Customers.Take(100))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@customer.Id</td>
                <td>@customer.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

To mitigate that, I replaced `th` with `tr` as follows.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>Id</tr>
        <tr>Name</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var customer in Model.Customers.Take(100))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@customer.Id</td>
                <td>@customer.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think in your case, you just needed to surround all your <th> elements in a row.
I have updated my answer to illustrate this